# ZF2 changing my expression and returning error (Postgre, Distinct)

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, zend-framework2

I have to make a SELECT where I will distinct the rows by the column idcontrato. I did it well with with SQL...

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (idcontrato) * 
FROM   cad_emprestimo 
WHERE  numerobeneficio = '1135346515';
```

But when I try to do the same with ZF2:

```
$emprestimos = (new EmprestimoTable())->select(function(Select $select) use($cliente) {
        $select->columns([new Expression('DISTINCT ON (idcontrato) *')]);
        $select->where->equalTo('numerobeneficio', $cliente->getBeneficio()->getNumero());
});
```

I got the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERRO:  erro de sintaxe em ou próximo a "AS"
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON (idcontrato) * AS Expression1 FROM "cad_e...
                                          ^
```

This 'AS Expression1' added by ZF2... I don't know how to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious solution I've found is to run the raw SQL:

```
    $dbAdapter      = GlobalAdapterFeature::getStaticAdapter();
    $numBeneficio   = $cliente->getBeneficio()->getNumero();
    $sqlEmprestimos = "SELECT DISTINCT ON (idcontrato) * FROM cad_emprestimo WHERE numerobeneficio = '".$numBeneficio."'; ";
    $dataSource     = $dbAdapter->createStatement($sqlEmprestimos)->execute();
    $emprestimos    = (new \Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet())->initialize($dataSource);
```

Anyway, I'm not happy with this, this code is ugly as hell.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
$emprestimos = (new EmprestimoTable())->select(function(Select $select) use($cliente) {
        $select->columns([new Expression('DISTINCT(idcontrato) AS idcontrato'), '*']);
        $select->where->equalTo('numerobeneficio', $cliente->getBeneficio()->getNumero());
});
```

Comment: if my answer is right then mark it as correct to help others facing same issue. glad to help.

Comment: I have already tried this solution, but it only reorders the result grouping by the colum idcontrato. I need to hide repeated values, and DISTINCT ON display a row only once if the column value defined on it was already shown.

`DISTINCT ON (idcontrato) * FROM...` is exactly what I need.

Thank you anyway.